# SSL certificate only valid when viewed externally

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a SSL certificate installed on our server.
When viewed externally it validates correctly, however when the website is viewed from the server it gets an invalid certificate error.

We are using the fully qualified domain name to access it for both?

Is there any reason this should be happening?
Cheers.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?  Pretty much all browsers give you a very specific error if you dig into the details.

Comment: Yes, what exactly is the error. Could be as simple as the certificate provider not being present in the "browser"s trusted certificate provider list.

Comment: please display the error, what server & what browser versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an internal DNS and are also the owner of the CA, you probably want to add internal DNS aliases to the certificate.

Here's a good article explaining it:
http://techblog.lucidillusion.org/2007/10/13/ssl-certificates-with-dns-aliases/

Answer (score 0):

What IP address is being used in both cases?  This problem can easily occur if you're poisoning your DNS on the server and hence connecting to a different IP address on the server, because SSL vhosts are typically attached to a particular IP address to ensure the correct certificate is returned.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you get on the server?  Might just be that the server doesn't trust the CA that created the cert.